# Making an authenticated request to the Github API in GAE using Python + urlfetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, github, urllib2, github-api

How do you make an authenticated request to the Github API once you've got the access token in GAE using Python and urlfetch?

Here is my code so far:

```
# Make an authenticated GET request to the Github API
url = 'https://api.github.com/user'
fields = {
    "access_token" : access_token,
}
data = urllib.urlencode(fields)
result = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=url,
    payload=data,
    method=urlfetch.GET,
)
```

And the error I get is:

```
{"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"http://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this so it makes a correct authenticated request?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this one was pretty simply, although it took me quite a while to get to it.

Here is the code to make an authenticated request to the Github on Google App Engine using Python/Urlfetch:

```
# Make an authenticated request
url = 'https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + str(access_token)
result = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=url,
    method=urlfetch.GET,
)
```